# SQL Server Table Valued Parameter. The type is 'Object'

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I am wanting to pass a DataTable as a parameter to a procedure, this DataTable has originated from an Excel spreadsheet which is then converted to DataTable.

In SQL I created a Type Table with the required fields, all columns with the same name as the DataTable it receives. In this Excel spreadsheet some fields can be null, that is, come in blank .. and these fields are properly informed in the Type that I created in SQL.

Below is the code for how I am passing the DataTable to the procedure

```
    public void ImportToSql(DataTable dt)
{

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"EXEC [dbo].AddPrextAndOperacoes @dataTable";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;               
            SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataTable", dt);
            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

            var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
            returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            var result = returnParameter.Value;
        }

}
```

The problem is that when it reported the following error when it encountered the first field with no value

> The type of column '{field}' is not supported. The type is 'Object'

Before passing dt as parameter to ImportToSql () I check if there is any column without value and add DBNull.Value, even then the error is presented

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
{
   foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
   {
     row[col] = row[col]?.ToString() == "" ? DBNull.Value : row[col];
   }
}
```

Comment: Can we see how you created the DataTable columns, please?

Comment: I am using a dll that you pass the worksheet as parameter and is returned a DataTable. Internally I do not know how you are creating this dt.

Comment: Not related to the error but you should specify only the proc name in the CommandText because CommandType.StoredProcedure is specified.

Comment: @DanGuzman Interesting point, thanks for this.

Comment: It seems ilke your issue came there. Some columns on your DataTable do not have the correct type. Put a break point somewhere after the DT generation and check the type of field's column.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Thanks for your attention! I did as requested and the 3 empty fields are with the DataType as {Name = "Object" FullName = "System.Object"}

Comment: The DLL that load your DT didn't set the correct type for some columns. So maybe it based its DT generation on the Types you set trhough the excel files. So check the documentation of the DLL and make sure that the columns of DT are correct.

Comment: @CodeNotFound I was able to correct it by changing the column type, as you said. Put your comment on the answers so I can mark it as correct.